# Node template file called for menu items

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am using D6... and in my node-blog.tpl.php file have added a check for whether the user is adult if not he should be redirected to the referrer page, now when i try to view my home page the user is redirected back to the referrer page.. just bcoz i have used a menu item for my blog node page?

how can i resolve this issue?

why is node-blog.tpl.php is called for menu items?

is this how drupal flow or am i making some mistake.. please help?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: A template file isn't really appropriate for doing this sort of check, can you post the code you're using at the moment?

Comment: if ($node->is_adult_blog[0]['value']) {
  drupal_set_message('THis is adult content');
  drupal_goto($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);
}

This code has been added at the top of the node-blog.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

This kind of check shouldn't be implemented in your tpl file. It should be done in a module by implementing either hook_nodeapi or hook_init.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6

OR

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7